# How to search using @ and # tags in input using ionic 4?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am making a post similar to a Facebook post, when I post data in the post when I type “@” to search data that return users names and if I type “#” first to call API and return available tags in ionic 4.

Here what I have done:

page.html

```
  <ion-item>
    <ion-textarea rows="3" (ionInput)="searchPeople($event)" cols="20" formControlName="comment"
      placeholder="Tweet your reply" spellcheck="true" autoComplete="true" autocorrect="true" autofocus required>
    </ion-textarea>
  </ion-item>
```

page.ts

```
searchPeople(ev: any) {
  // set val to the value of the searchbar
  let val = ev.target.value;
  let firstchar = val.charAt(0);

  if (firstchar = "@") {
    console.log("search people");
  }
  else if (firstchar = "#") {
    console.log("hash tag");
  } else {
   console.log("error");
  }
}
```

I did like this but it’s not working…

Comment: you should compare not assign change firstchar = "@"  firstchar == "@"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **HTML:**

Change `(ionInput)="searchPeople($event)"` to `(input)="searchPeople($event)"`..

And in

**TS:** Change the function like,

```
if (firstchar === "@") {
    console.log("search people");
  }
  else if (firstchar === "#") {
    console.log("hash tag");
  } else {
   console.log("error");
  }
```

Here the `firstchar` needs to check for value and it should not assign value.

**Working Example:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-basic-form-1bjibt

Answer (score 1):

[working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qmc2rf)

> page.html

```
 <ion-item>
    <ion-textarea rows="3"  (input)="searchPeople($event.target.value)"
      placeholder="Tweet your reply" spellcheck="true" autoComplete="true" autocorrect="true" autofocus required>
    </ion-textarea>
  </ion-item>
```

> page.ts

```
searchPeople(searchValue : string ) {  
console.log(searchValue);
let firstchar === searchValue;

  if (firstchar === "@") {
    console.log("search people");
  }
  else if (firstchar === "#") {
    console.log("hash tag");
  } else {
   console.log("error");
  }
}
}
```